# Integrating prettyPhoto into Wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, prettyphoto

I am trying to integrate prettyPhoto into my Wordpress theme (i'm using the Sydney theme). I have done the following:

1. uploaded the prettyPhoto.css file into the /css directory
2. uploaded the jquery-1.3.2.min.js and jquery.prettyPhoto.js files into the /js directory
3. uploaded all of the image folders (fullscreen, prettyPhoto, thumbails) into the /images directory

then, I added

```html
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
<script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

to the header.php file, right after the opening  tag, like this:

```html
?php
/**
 * The header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="content">
 *
 * @package Sydney
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
<script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
<?php if ( ! function_exists( 'has_site_icon' ) || ! has_site_icon() ) : ?>
 <?php if ( get_theme_mod('site_favicon') ) : ?>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo esc_url(get_theme_mod('site_favicon')); ?>" />
 <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_head(); ?>

<!--
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#button').click(function(e) {  
        var inputvalue3 = $("#input").val();
        

    });
});
</script> 
-->


</head>
```

then, to initialize prettyPhoto, I added

```html
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
  });
</script>
```

into the footer.php file, right before the closing  tag, like this:

```html
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer.
 *
 * Contains the closing of the #content div and all content after
 *
 * @package Sydney
 */
?>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div><!-- #content -->

 <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'footer-1' ) ) : ?>
  <?php get_sidebar('footer'); ?>
 <?php endif; ?>

    <a class="go-top"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></a>

 <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
  <div class="site-info container">
   <a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( 'http://wordpress.org/', 'sydney' ) ); ?>"><?php printf( __( 'Proudly powered by %s', 'sydney' ), 'WordPress' ); ?></a>
   <span class="sep"> | </span>
   <?php printf( __( 'Theme: %2$s by %1$s.', 'sydney' ), 'aThemes', '<a href="http://athemes.com/theme/sydney" rel="designer">Sydney</a>' ); ?>
  </div><!-- .site-info -->
 </footer><!-- #colophon -->
</div><!-- #page -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
  });
</script>
</body>
```

Now, on my wordpress page, there is a section, which is described by a file called "fp-call-to-action.php"

This file includes a button. Upon clicking the button, I want a youtube video to open in a lightbox, using prettyPhoto:

```html
<div>
                        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=40wYKjSd9r0" rel="prettyPhoto" title="youtube">
                        <button type="button" id="button">Jetzt anschauen!</button>
                        </a>
                        </div>
```

However, every time i click on the button, i get redirected to youtube. the video just won't open in a lightbox.

where am i making a mistake?

many thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to resolve the problem. The links were wrongly, total rookie mistake. My apologies!